# ordered list from bottom to top

Tags: html, html-lists

Is it possible to make ordered list (ol) starting from the last number? For ex

5 - sasasasa

4 - sasasas

3 - sasasas

2 - sasasa

1 - sasasas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HTML 5 introduces

```
<ol reversed>
```

See an example at http://www.w3schools.com/html5/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_ol

Otherwise you're stuck with specifying a value for each item

```
<ol>
<li value="5">Item 5</li>
<li value="4">Item 4</li>
...
</ol>
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning `reversed`, however this is only supported by chrome and safari at the moment (i have no idea about Opera and IE planning to support this, fur Firefox theres a bug-report: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=601912).

Answer (score -1):

Use JQuery to reverse the list, e.g.:

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
       var countli = $('ol > li').size();
       $("ol > li").each(function(i) {
             var attrvalue = countli - i;
             $(this).attr("value",attrvalue);
       });
    });
```